# Count total bookings by category - Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

My BookingGroup has_many Booking. Booking contains column `category` where the data can be "adult" or "child_infant" or child_normal.

Now I want to count all total %child% and display it in my index view table

I was'nt sure whether this could be done in one line or I have to use a scope, this is where I stucked.

`BookingGroup` model

```
  def search_by_category
    bookings.visible.map(&:category).inject(:+)
  end
```

Comment: can you try this `bookings.left_outer_joins(:category).visible.group('categories.name').count` ?

Comment: is there a way i can specify it only count the child? @Vishal

Comment: bookings.left_outer_joins(:category).visible.where("categories.name = 'child'").group('categories.name')

Comment: Can't join 'Booking' to association named 'category'; perhaps you misspelled it? @Vishal

Comment: if category is model then what is association between booking  and category? if its field of booking table `bookings.visible.where("category = 'child'").group('category')`

Comment: no2, the category is one of column under Booking model @Vishal

Comment: `bookings.visible.where("category = 'child'").group('category').count` try this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming category is a string column, you should be able to count it like that :

```
bookings.visible.where("category LIKE ?", "child%").count

bookings.visible.where(category: ["child_infant", "child_normal"]).count
```

Comment: the first answer showing an error of relation, i wasnt sure why, but the second one works like a charm, ill take all of this as a future reference, thanks in advance.

Comment: @DanielSufian can you show me the error so I fix it please ?

Comment: PG::UndefinedFunction: ERROR:  operator does not exist: integer ~~ unknown
LINE 1: ...id" = $1 AND (bookings.status != 1) AND (category LIKE 'chil...
                                                             ^
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.

Comment: @DanielSufian Is your `category` column an `integer` ?

Comment: @DanielSufian LIKE operator only works for strings that's why. So do you use enums ? I might have another solution for you.

Comment: can i have the link if you dont mind? so i can understand a little bit more

Comment: SQL LIKE operator tutorial : https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-like-clause.htm

Answer (score 0):

We can use `LIKE` just as in SQL with active record

In your `BookingGroup` model

```
def search_by_category
    bookings.visible.where('category LIKE ?', '%child%').size
end
```

But, if you do so for many `booking_groups`, your code will have `N+1` queries issue. You can use eager load in your controller

```
@booking_groups = BookingGroup.joins(:bookings).select('booking_groups.*', 'count(*) as total_bookings').where('bookings.category LIKE ?', '%child%').group(:id)
```

Then you can

```
@booking_groups.first.total_bookings
```